# How to add apt repository with Ubuntu autoinstall

Tags: apt, system-installation, curtin

I'm trying to test out the Ubuntu autoinstall and I'm struggling to figure out how to work with the apt section.

My goal is to install for example git and docker, which would look like that on a regular terminal installation:

```
#Python3.6
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
apt-get update
apt-get install python3.6 -y
#Docker -
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

I read the documentation of the autoinstall - https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference

And the referenced documentation of Curtin at - https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apt_source.html

However, it's not soo clear to me who should I add the repositories.

Would appreciate any guidance or a working example.

Comment: Your question does not mention your release of Ubuntu, nor whether you are using the Desktop or Server installer. It makes a difference: Those determine whether you should be using Preseed or Cloud-init.

Answer (score 6):

This config snippet adds the repositories to the installed system

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
      - arches: [amd64, i386]
        uri: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
      - arches: [default]
        uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
    sources:
      deadsnakes-ppa:
        source: ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
      docker:
        source: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
        key: |
          -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

          mQINBFit2ioBEADhWpZ8/wvZ6hUTiXOwQHXMAlaFHcPH9hAtr4F1y2+OYdbtMuth
          lqqwp028AqyY+PRfVMtSYMbjuQuu5byyKR01BbqYhuS3jtqQmljZ/bJvXqnmiVXh
          38UuLa+z077PxyxQhu5BbqntTPQMfiyqEiU+BKbq2WmANUKQf+1AmZY/IruOXbnq
          L4C1+gJ8vfmXQt99npCaxEjaNRVYfOS8QcixNzHUYnb6emjlANyEVlZzeqo7XKl7
          UrwV5inawTSzWNvtjEjj4nJL8NsLwscpLPQUhTQ+7BbQXAwAmeHCUTQIvvWXqw0N
          cmhh4HgeQscQHYgOJjjDVfoY5MucvglbIgCqfzAHW9jxmRL4qbMZj+b1XoePEtht
          ku4bIQN1X5P07fNWzlgaRL5Z4POXDDZTlIQ/El58j9kp4bnWRCJW0lya+f8ocodo
          vZZ+Doi+fy4D5ZGrL4XEcIQP/Lv5uFyf+kQtl/94VFYVJOleAv8W92KdgDkhTcTD
          G7c0tIkVEKNUq48b3aQ64NOZQW7fVjfoKwEZdOqPE72Pa45jrZzvUFxSpdiNk2tZ
          XYukHjlxxEgBdC/J3cMMNRE1F4NCA3ApfV1Y7/hTeOnmDuDYwr9/obA8t016Yljj
          q5rdkywPf4JF8mXUW5eCN1vAFHxeg9ZWemhBtQmGxXnw9M+z6hWwc6ahmwARAQAB
          tCtEb2NrZXIgUmVsZWFzZSAoQ0UgZGViKSA8ZG9ja2VyQGRvY2tlci5jb20+iQI3
          BBMBCgAhBQJYrefAAhsvBQsJCAcDBRUKCQgLBRYCAwEAAh4BAheAAAoJEI2BgDwO
          v82IsskP/iQZo68flDQmNvn8X5XTd6RRaUH33kXYXquT6NkHJciS7E2gTJmqvMqd
          tI4mNYHCSEYxI5qrcYV5YqX9P6+Ko+vozo4nseUQLPH/ATQ4qL0Zok+1jkag3Lgk
          jonyUf9bwtWxFp05HC3GMHPhhcUSexCxQLQvnFWXD2sWLKivHp2fT8QbRGeZ+d3m
          6fqcd5Fu7pxsqm0EUDK5NL+nPIgYhN+auTrhgzhK1CShfGccM/wfRlei9Utz6p9P
          XRKIlWnXtT4qNGZNTN0tR+NLG/6Bqd8OYBaFAUcue/w1VW6JQ2VGYZHnZu9S8LMc
          FYBa5Ig9PxwGQOgq6RDKDbV+PqTQT5EFMeR1mrjckk4DQJjbxeMZbiNMG5kGECA8
          g383P3elhn03WGbEEa4MNc3Z4+7c236QI3xWJfNPdUbXRaAwhy/6rTSFbzwKB0Jm
          ebwzQfwjQY6f55MiI/RqDCyuPj3r3jyVRkK86pQKBAJwFHyqj9KaKXMZjfVnowLh
          9svIGfNbGHpucATqREvUHuQbNnqkCx8VVhtYkhDb9fEP2xBu5VvHbR+3nfVhMut5
          G34Ct5RS7Jt6LIfFdtcn8CaSas/l1HbiGeRgc70X/9aYx/V/CEJv0lIe8gP6uDoW
          FPIZ7d6vH+Vro6xuWEGiuMaiznap2KhZmpkgfupyFmplh0s6knymuQINBFit2ioB
          EADneL9S9m4vhU3blaRjVUUyJ7b/qTjcSylvCH5XUE6R2k+ckEZjfAMZPLpO+/tF
          M2JIJMD4SifKuS3xck9KtZGCufGmcwiLQRzeHF7vJUKrLD5RTkNi23ydvWZgPjtx
          Q+DTT1Zcn7BrQFY6FgnRoUVIxwtdw1bMY/89rsFgS5wwuMESd3Q2RYgb7EOFOpnu
          w6da7WakWf4IhnF5nsNYGDVaIHzpiqCl+uTbf1epCjrOlIzkZ3Z3Yk5CM/TiFzPk
          z2lLz89cpD8U+NtCsfagWWfjd2U3jDapgH+7nQnCEWpROtzaKHG6lA3pXdix5zG8
          eRc6/0IbUSWvfjKxLLPfNeCS2pCL3IeEI5nothEEYdQH6szpLog79xB9dVnJyKJb
          VfxXnseoYqVrRz2VVbUI5Blwm6B40E3eGVfUQWiux54DspyVMMk41Mx7QJ3iynIa
          1N4ZAqVMAEruyXTRTxc9XW0tYhDMA/1GYvz0EmFpm8LzTHA6sFVtPm/ZlNCX6P1X
          zJwrv7DSQKD6GGlBQUX+OeEJ8tTkkf8QTJSPUdh8P8YxDFS5EOGAvhhpMBYD42kQ
          pqXjEC+XcycTvGI7impgv9PDY1RCC1zkBjKPa120rNhv/hkVk/YhuGoajoHyy4h7
          ZQopdcMtpN2dgmhEegny9JCSwxfQmQ0zK0g7m6SHiKMwjwARAQABiQQ+BBgBCAAJ
          BQJYrdoqAhsCAikJEI2BgDwOv82IwV0gBBkBCAAGBQJYrdoqAAoJEH6gqcPyc/zY
          1WAP/2wJ+R0gE6qsce3rjaIz58PJmc8goKrir5hnElWhPgbq7cYIsW5qiFyLhkdp
          YcMmhD9mRiPpQn6Ya2w3e3B8zfIVKipbMBnke/ytZ9M7qHmDCcjoiSmwEXN3wKYI
          mD9VHONsl/CG1rU9Isw1jtB5g1YxuBA7M/m36XN6x2u+NtNMDB9P56yc4gfsZVES
          KA9v+yY2/l45L8d/WUkUi0YXomn6hyBGI7JrBLq0CX37GEYP6O9rrKipfz73XfO7
          JIGzOKZlljb/D9RX/g7nRbCn+3EtH7xnk+TK/50euEKw8SMUg147sJTcpQmv6UzZ
          cM4JgL0HbHVCojV4C/plELwMddALOFeYQzTif6sMRPf+3DSj8frbInjChC3yOLy0
          6br92KFom17EIj2CAcoeq7UPhi2oouYBwPxh5ytdehJkoo+sN7RIWua6P2WSmon5
          U888cSylXC0+ADFdgLX9K2zrDVYUG1vo8CX0vzxFBaHwN6Px26fhIT1/hYUHQR1z
          VfNDcyQmXqkOnZvvoMfz/Q0s9BhFJ/zU6AgQbIZE/hm1spsfgvtsD1frZfygXJ9f
          irP+MSAI80xHSf91qSRZOj4Pl3ZJNbq4yYxv0b1pkMqeGdjdCYhLU+LZ4wbQmpCk
          SVe2prlLureigXtmZfkqevRz7FrIZiu9ky8wnCAPwC7/zmS18rgP/17bOtL4/iIz
          QhxAAoAMWVrGyJivSkjhSGx1uCojsWfsTAm11P7jsruIL61ZzMUVE2aM3Pmj5G+W
          9AcZ58Em+1WsVnAXdUR//bMmhyr8wL/G1YO1V3JEJTRdxsSxdYa4deGBBY/Adpsw
          24jxhOJR+lsJpqIUeb999+R8euDhRHG9eFO7DRu6weatUJ6suupoDTRWtr/4yGqe
          dKxV3qQhNLSnaAzqW/1nA3iUB4k7kCaKZxhdhDbClf9P37qaRW467BLCVO/coL3y
          Vm50dwdrNtKpMBh3ZpbB1uJvgi9mXtyBOMJ3v8RZeDzFiG8HdCtg9RvIt/AIFoHR
          H3S+U79NT6i0KPzLImDfs8T7RlpyuMc4Ufs8ggyg9v3Ae6cN3eQyxcK3w0cbBwsh
          /nQNfsA6uu+9H7NhbehBMhYnpNZyrHzCmzyXkauwRAqoCbGCNykTRwsur9gS41TQ
          M8ssD1jFheOJf3hODnkKU+HKjvMROl1DK7zdmLdNzA1cvtZH/nCC9KPj1z8QC47S
          xx+dTZSx4ONAhwbS/LN3PoKtn8LPjY9NP9uDWI+TWYquS2U+KHDrBDlsgozDbs/O
          jCxcpDzNmXpWQHEtHU7649OXHP7UeNST1mCUCH5qdank0V1iejF6/CfTFU4MfcrG
          YT90qFF93M3v01BbxP+EIY2/9tiIPbrd
          =0YYh
          -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: You really helped me out thanks. I'm not sure why the docs don't have a concise clear example like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu auto install uses cloud-init yaml files which is a brilliant way of doing unattended installs of Ubuntu.   However there is a bit of a learning curve.

The cloud-init documentation has this as an example:
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#add-primary-apt-repositories

For example, the cloud-init yaml user-data for installing and running docker.io:

```
#cloud-config
timezone: 'Europe/London'
package_update: 'true'
packages:
  - build-essential
  - docker.io
write_files:
  - path: /etc/systemd/system/container.service
    owner: root:root
    permissions: '0755'
    content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Run container
        Requires=docker.service
        After=docker.service

        [Service]
        Restart=always
        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm container
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name container hello-world
        ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 2 container

runcmd:
  - systemctl start container
  - systemctl enable container
```

Comment: I don't see `write_files` in the [autoinstall config reference](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference). Is it described somewhere else?

Comment: That’s because under the user-data: section it’s plain old cloud init which is run on first boot rather than auto-install.