# Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 autoinstall adding apt sources crashes the installer

Tags: apt

I am trying to add custom .list entries to sources.d no matter what I do it always crashes the installer,
The Ubuntu autoinstall reference documentation only shows you how to add a ppa not a .list file, the curtin docs give you the syntax for .list but I cant get it to work. The primary repo gets added no problems if I only use that, but sources have me stumped.

Any ideas

```
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  apt:
    primary:
      -  arches: [amd64]
         uri: https://redacted.com
    sources:
      aaa.list:
        source: "deb https://redacted repo aaa"
      bbb.list:
        source:  "deb https://redacted repo bbb"
      ccc.list:
        source: "deb [trusted=yes] https://redacted repo ccc"
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1326176/376778 for an example of adding repos.  I think your yaml is ok.  I'd guess that your `aaa` and `bbb` repositories are failing because there is no `key`.

Comment: I have tried with the key it doesnt work. It seems ubutnu autoinstall is not 100% compatible with the curtin syntax. You can add ppa like you mentioned, but it doesnt work for sources.list No big deal I can do what I need with cgf mgmt afterwards.

Comment: You can check what curtin syntax is being generated by subiquity for curtin if you open a shell in the installer and look at `/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-apt.conf`.

Comment: Im also having this same issue. Havent been able to figure out how to add the cloudflared repository to my autoinstall. Without the cloudflared source, it works perfectly. Once I add it in, it breaks. And I am including the keys with it.