# Error while using private Apt repos during autoinstall installation

Tags: apt, system-installation, repository

#### Overview / Scenario

I already have a fully working autoinstall configuration that is using the default apt configuration (no apt config in cloud-init user data). The source image is using [the Ubuntu 20.04 cloud image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/).

My goal is to edit the autoinstall config to use private Apt repos (the repos already exist). I must ensure the installer never reaches out to Ubuntu servers for Apt packages and ***only*** hits custom Apt repos. The repos are already established and have been working for a long time, I just need to get the installer to point to them.

I have already reviewed [How to add apt repository with Ubuntu autoinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326043/how-to-add-apt-repository-with-ubuntu-autoinstall)

#### Here is what I've added to the autoinstall cloud init:

***Note:** the below mentioned `/cdrom/apt-key.gpg` file is present and valid for the repo (tested thoroughly).*

***Note:** The repos are over https using private CA. Since I can't install the `ca-certificates` package yet during install before configuring Apt, I'm just forcing it to be trusted. `trusted=yes` didn't work, I had to also add the `apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf` as shown below to get it to work. This **may be** a cause for the issue but it works fine manually at an install shell. I have the certs and can inject them into the install media, so if there is a better way to get the installer instance to trust my CA cert without having to force trust, I'm open to that change!*

```
  early-commands:
    - 'mkdir -p /etc/apt'
    - 'cp /cdrom/apt-key.gpg /etc/apt/fresh-ubuntu-key.gpg'
    - 'touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf'
    - 'echo >>/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99verify-peer.conf "Acquire { https::Verify-Peer false }"'
  apt:
    preserve_sources_list: false
    sources_list: |
      deb [trusted=yes signed-by=/etc/apt/fresh-ubuntu-key.gpg] https://repo.internal.example.com/aptly/focal focal-ver221 main
      deb [trusted=yes signed-by=/etc/apt/fresh-ubuntu-key.gpg] https://repo.internal.example.com/aptly/focal focal-security-ver221 main
      deb [trusted=yes signed-by=/etc/apt/fresh-ubuntu-key.gpg] https://repo.internal.example.com/aptly/focal focal-updates-ver221 main
      deb [trusted=yes signed-by=/etc/apt/fresh-ubuntu-key.gpg] https://repo.internal.example.com/aptly/focal focal-backports-ver221 main
```

#### Problem / Troubleshooting

When trying to install, it fails with the following:

```
finish: subiquity/Updates/apply_autoinstall_config
start: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config
finish: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config
start: subiquity/Shutdown/apply_autoinstall_config
finish: subiquity/Shutdown/apply_autoinstall_config
finish: subiquity/apply_autoinstall_config
start:   subiquity/Install/install/configure_apt: configuring apt
start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET
start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET
start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET
start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET
start: subiquity/Mirror/cmd-apt-config: curtin command apt-config
finish: subiquity/Mirror/cmd-apt-config: curtin command apt-config
start:     subiquity/Install/install/configure_apt/cmd-in-target: curtin command in-target
finish:   subiquity/Install/install/configure_apt: Command '['/snap/subiquity/3119/usr/bin/python3.8', '-m', 'curtin', '--showtrace', '-vvv', '--set', 'json:reporting={"subiquity": {"type": "journald", "identifier": "curtin_event.2752.2"}}', 'in-target', '-t', '/tmp/tmpzyqgk825/mount', '--', 'apt-get', 'update']' returned non-zero exit status 100.
finish: subiquity/Install/install: Command '['/snap/subiquity/3119/usr/bin/python3.8', '-m', 'curtin', '--showtrace', '-vvv', '--set', 'json:reporting={"subiquity": {"type": "journald", "identifier": "curtin_event.2752.2"}}', 'in-target', '-t', '/tmp/tmpzyqgk825/mount', '--', 'apt-get', 'update']' returned non-zero exit status 100.
start:   subiquity/ErrorReporter/1669932701.344982386.install_fail/add_info
finish:     subiquity/Install/install/configure_apt/cmd-in-target: curtin command in-target
finish:   subiquity/ErrorReporter/1669932701.344982386.install_fail/add_info: written to /var/crash/1669932701.344982386.install_fail.crash
An error occurred. Press enter to start a shell
```

I tried finding anything meaningful in `/var/crash/1669932701.344982386.install_fail.crash` but it's a massive file and hard to parse. Doesn't seem to have any additional failure info that I can see.

**Important Note:**
After it fails, I can drop into a shell, update /etc/apt/sources.list manually and `apt update` works perfectly fine. So I know that the installer instance CAN properly communicate with my private repos. So it seems the issue has to be something specific during autoinstall/cloud-init.

Please help if you have any ideas, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

You could try something like

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  apt:
    preserve_sources_list: false
    sources_list: |
      deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.internal.example.com/aptly/focal focal-ver221 main
      deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.internal.example.com/aptly/focal focal-security-ver221 main
      deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.internal.example.com/aptly/focal focal-updates-ver221 main
      deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.internal.example.com/aptly/focal focal-backports-ver221 main
     conf: |
      Acquire::https::repo.internal.example.com::Verify-Peer "false";
      Acquire::https::repo.internal.example.com::Verify-Host "false";
```

**reasoning**

To start, the `early-commands` in your autoinstall config are not doing what you seem to think.  The commands are configuring apt within the installer environment.  However, the apt commands during installation generally happen in a different `chroot` environment.  The logs you shared show this.  The failing command is partially `in-target -t /tmp/tmpzyqgk825/mount apt-get update`.

The second issue is that the repository has a custom gpg key.  The only way to provide a custom key that I am aware of is using the syntax in [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326043/how-to-add-apt-repository-with-ubuntu-autoinstall) you referenced.  You can certainly also add the `sources.list` option `trusted=yes` to avoid a failure from the missing gpg key, but that is probably not a good configuration in the long run.

The third issue is that a private CA signed the https certificate.  There is no provided way to trust this private CA.  It looks like [a bug has been filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1951994) requesting this.  It also looks like [there is an apt configuration option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317695/is-it-possible-to-have-apt-accept-an-invalid-certificate) that can be used to ignore the certificate problems.  Again, that is probably not a good configuration in the long run.

It is probably easiest to `late-commands` to install the custom gpg key and the private CA, and reconfigure apt.

**update**

As noted in the comments, this solution did not work. I'm sharing what I found here.  I tested the install process using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`).

- *subiquity* [creates](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/872414259276e01e8c40fa579d20b4f48d8e864c/subiquity/server/apt.py#L85) `/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-apt.conf`.  It basically contains the autoinstall `apt` section (and potentially proxy information).
- *subiquity* runs *curtin* to [configure apt](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/872414259276e01e8c40fa579d20b4f48d8e864c/subiquity/server/apt.py#L99) using `/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-apt.conf` in the `/tmp/tmpXXX` overlay file system.  If my autoinstall snippet above is used then *curtin* will create `/tmp/tmpXXX/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/94curtin-config`.
- *subiquity* creates `/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf`.  This does **not** contain an [apt section](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/0f987ee6bae2848796b9ac46165c8a50b414b677/subiquity/models/mirror.py#L87).  Presumably, because apt is configured already.
- *subiquity* runs *curtin* to [perform the install](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/0e846cd88ca8dc894d0088d8e7d28f262ff191a6/subiquity/server/controllers/install.py#L112) using `/var/log/installer/subiquity-curtin-install.conf`.  This will copy `/tmp/tmpXXX` to `/target`.  This creates `/target/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/94curtin-config`.
- At a later stage during the install, *curtin* [configures apt](https://github.com/canonical/curtin/blob/1fc717df52ec15f616d26fff3c10bff181599b30/curtin/commands/curthooks.py#L1709).  Because the install configuration does not contain the apt section *curtin* will actually [delete 94curtin-config](https://github.com/canonical/curtin/blob/1797204fd5df4e0a647d73734e2f47691828c0a1/curtin/commands/apt_config.py#L617).
- Subsequent apt commands that require the apt configuration in `94curtin-config` will fail and cause the installation to fail.
- If the installation does not fail because of the missing `94curtin-config` file then a later step in *subiquity* [will copy](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/872414259276e01e8c40fa579d20b4f48d8e864c/subiquity/server/apt.py#L165) `/tmp/tmpXXX/etc/apt` to `/target/etc/apt` and the resulting installation will contain `94curtin-config`.

In short, do not depend on the `apt` `conf` settings using autoinstall.

Comment: Thank you! The key takeaway here is that `early-commands` wasn't working as I was expecting because the installation is working within a chroot directory. That explains the behavior and I was able to get this working using your config example. I'll use the custom gpg key but ignore the https validation. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: To anyone reading this in the future, I still could not get this to work because the `Verify-Peer` and `Verify-Host` config overrides are seemingly ignored during the install process (maybe apt-transport-https isnt available?). Instead of fighting it more I just updated the repo to accept `http://` connections.

Comment: I tested again and the installer did fail, but it fails much later than without the `conf` setting.  The apt configuration options do get installed into `/tmp/tmpXXX/mount/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/94curtin-config`, but that does not get copied over to `/target/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.  Probably a gap in _subiquity_'s logic.  In general, I do think it is much easier to use a basic apt configuration and then change settings in `late-commands`.  The installer simply does not have enough hooks to allow customization like installing gpg keys, installing trusted certificates, or adding apt configuration.

Comment: I did some more digging into why this fails.  Unfortunately, it did not lead to a solution.  I dumped what I found into the answer in case anybody else tries something similar.

Comment: Your effort is appreciated!