autoinstall fully offline iso with ubuntu jammy live ISO
I am trying a jammy live iso customization, and when I boot the ISO, installer crashes!
Specifically, subiquity/Install/install/configure_apt/cmd-in-target errors out and
the reason being apt-get update failure.
apt-get update errors out due to GPG key (NO_PUBKEY XYZ...)
So, I tried adding the following autoinstall config:
  apt:
    conf: | # APT config
      APT {
        Get {
          AllowUnauthenticated "true";
        };
      };


But this does not seem to be taking effect!
The syntax seems to be correct and I picked this up from curtin examples.
Isn't there no equivalent of apt's  --allow-unauthenticated that I
can pass to the autoinstaller/curtin?

You can't rely on the conf settings to always be set.  You can specify the apt source as deb [trusted=yes] http....  See https://askubuntu.com/q/1443497/376778

@AndrewLowther , I tried to edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list and re-run curtin on the failed ISO installer shell, but it still errored out that Release is not signed!  The line was like: deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server ...<version,timestamp>]/ jammy extras main restricted
I changed this to :
deb cdrom:[trusted=yes]/ jammy extras main restricted  Is this correct syntax ? Do I have to do some gpg signing - is that a  mandatory step ?

I tried Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories true that seems to help! I will probe further

With a cdrom URI the syntax would be deb [trusted=yes] cdrom:...
